# Four-term formula for accelerating sums of alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Has anyone seen this formula that I worked out, which is based on averaging:

a is the first term, on down to d is the fourth term.

Sum ~ (1/16)[16a + 15b + 10c + 3d]

If a = 4, on down to d = -4/7 for the pi formula, then the approximation gives about 3.142.

Or, for example, you can add, starting with 4 on down to -4/7 exactly.   Then take a = 4/9 on down to d = -4/15.  Add the first sum to the formula approximation to get the pi approximation.

This will give a better approximation.  Depending on where the a-value begins, the approximation will either be under or over.

This will work for estimating ln(2) and countless others.

Comment: Can you please explain where you got your coefficients from? The approximation is surprisingly good applied to the Dirichlet eta function series.

Comment: @ Somos -- Instead of that, I can give the formula to you to call your own.  You can call it the Somos Formula, or something to your choosing.